# How to configure firewall for home PC

Tags: 11.10, security

Firstly, for a home PC, behind a router isit important to install/configure a firewall?

If so, how do I do it? I have `lamp-server` installed as I'm a web developer. I may want my other PC's on LAN to access my files or web pages, ssh in (maybe in the future), but not from outside. How can I configure this? From work, I learnt that I keep blocking myself all the time, also `denyhosts` is useful for bruteforce hacking. But problem is I am not a System Admin so I keep blocking myself (including others) instead. Maybe `gufw + denyhosts` maybe a good start

Comment: Your router/dsl modem should by default block any http port from the internet, you have to set a port forward to enable internet access to your http server - I doubt you need a firewall if you only have a LAN-only service for a home pc. Depends on the level of security you wish to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question if fairly broad and I will try to answer some parts.

A firewall can be helpful for you, and you already know what you want - allow clients on your LAN and deny everyone else.

So, first thing, your router. Disable UPnP and do not forward port 80 (http) or 443 (https). If you need , you can forward SSH (port 22).

**On the server you can then significantly increase ssh security if you use ssh keys (to log in) and disable passwords.**

[Ubuntu wiki ssh keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)

denyhosts can be helpful, but the lockouts are a hassle. You can whitelist an IP or ip range.

For some advice on denyhost see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/block-ssh-attacks-with-denyhosts/ or the denyhosts documentation.

Now for your firewall , you can easily use ufw or if you want a graphical front end gufw.

Assuming you want just HTTP and SSH (change `192.168.0.0/24` to your LAN):

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 80
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 443 

# for ssh from anywhere
sudo ufw allow ssh

# for ssh from your lan only
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 22
```

See also [Ubuntu wiki UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)

Answer (score 0):

If you use your home machine for developing anything for a client, or have sensitive information on there it is worth looking at the benefits.

As @medigeek said, it may be overkill for you, as your ISP's router/modem will give some protection. It may by default deny all inbound until you open a route in.

However - if you take the usual security assumption that at some point someone or something malicious may get past that router (through an unpatched or zero-day vulnerability, a misconfiguration, via your file server or web server etc) **what protection do you have**, and **how much do you want?**

I generally advise anyone who even does online banking to have a layered approach:

- deny all inbound on the router
- host firewall (whether they are on Windows, Linux or other)
- look at DMZ's if you run a range of servers at home
- ensure all accessible machines are patched up to date

These are all simple options which require very little maintenance for a standard home setup with <10 servers or PC's